# I cannot edit date and time

Tags: java, date, jsf, formatting

When I try to edit date and time, I cannot. It shows the error:

> Cannot format given Object as a Date.

This is RegistroBean

```
public String Editar(Integer id){
    Registros r=this.registrosFacade.find(id);
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
    String strDate = dateFormatter.format(fecha);
    fecha = strDate;
    this.fecha=r.getFecha().toString();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss 'Z'");  
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String strHour = dateFormat.format(hora_in);
    hora_in = strHour;
    this.hora_in=r.getHoraIn().toString();
    String strHour2 = dateFormat.format(hora_out);
    hora_out = strHour2;
    this.hora_out=r.getHoraOut().toString();

    this.vehiculo=r.getIdVehiculo();
    return "RegistroEdit";
}

public String GuardarEdicion(RegistroController rc, int id) throws ParseException{
    Registros r = new Registros();
    Locale locale = new Locale("es","CO");
    String datef = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datef, locale);
    Date parsedDate = formatter.parse(fecha);
    r.setFecha(parsedDate);
    String hourf = "HH:mm:ss 'Z'";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(hourf, locale);
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date Hin = format.parse(hora_in);
    r.setHoraIn(Hin);
    Date Hout = format.parse(hora_out);
    r.setHoraOut(Hout);
    r.setIdVehiculo(vehiculosFacade.find(vehiculo.getId()));
    this.registrosFacade.edit(r);
    return "RegistroList";
}
```

In the list view when I edit, I click on this button:

```
<h:commandButton value="Editar" action="#{registroController.Editar(item.id)}"/>
```

this is RegistroEdit.xhtml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
         xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
         xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
     <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
     </h:head>
     <h:body>
        <f:view>

            <h:form>
                <h1><h:outputText value="Editar Registro"/></h1>
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <p:outputLabel value="Fecha:" for="fecha" />
                    <p:inputText id="fecha" value="#{registroController.fecha}" title="Fecha" >

                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:outputLabel value="HoraIn:" for="horaIn" />
                    <p:inputText id="horaIn" value="#{registroController.hora_in}" title="HoraIn" required="true" requiredMessage="The HoraIn field is required.">

                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:outputLabel value="HoraOut:" for="horaOut" />
                    <p:inputText id="horaOut" value="#{registroController.hora_out}" title="HoraOut" required="true" requiredMessage="The HoraOut field is required.">

                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:outputLabel value="IdVehiculo:" for="idVehiculo" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="idVehiculo" value="#{registroController.vehiculo.id}" required="true" requiredMessage="The IdVehiculo field is required.">
                        <!-- TODO: update below reference to list of available items-->
                        <f:selectItems value="#{vehiculoController.findAll()}" var="v" itemLabel="#{v.placa}" itemValue="#{v.id}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:commandButton id="registroCommand" value="Guardar"
                                  action="#{registroController.GuardarEdicion(registroController, registroController.id)}"/>          
                    <h:commandButton id="registroCommand1" value="Ir a Lista"
                                 action="#{registro.prepareList()}"/> 
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

trying to edit date and time it appears in the list view in this format:

fecha: Sun May 27 00:00:00 COT 2018

hora_in: Thu Jan 01 06:15:30 COT 1970

hora_out: Thu Jan 01 14:30:00 COT 1970

should appear the date and time in this format

fecha: 05/27/2018

hora_in: 06:15:30

hora_out: 14:30:00

What should I change to convert date to string without any error?

Comment: `dateFormatter.format(fecha);` it looks like `fecha` has not been set as this time

Comment: first of the database I bring the value with a get of the fecha, I do not know how to convert date to string

Comment: `dateFormatter.format(dateObject)`

Comment: Could I try dateFormatter.format (r.getDate ()), if it would work?

Comment: I have no idea - does `r.getDate ()` return a Date?

Comment: yes, r.getDate () return a Date.

Comment: Too much code. Post only the minimum to show your issue.

Comment: In that case [@ScaryWombat’s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520625/i-can-not-edit-date-and-time#comment88053814_50520625) works. I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, though. That class is notoriously troublesome, and along with `Date` and `DateFormat` long outdated. Look into [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Comment: [How (and when and why) to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on understanding your methods out of context. I think you’re after something like the following.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter. ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss X");

    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
    LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.now(offset);
    OffsetTime horaIn = OffsetTime.of(15, 0, 0, 0, offset);
    OffsetTime horaOut = OffsetTime.of(17, 37, 15, 0, offset);

    String strDate = fecha.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(strDate);
    String strHourIn = horaIn.format(timeFormatter);
    System.out.println(strHourIn);
    String strHourOut = horaOut.format(timeFormatter);
    System.out.println(strHourOut);
```

This code prints:

```
05/25/2018
15:00:00 Z
17:37:15 Z
```

I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome, and along with `Date` and `DateFormat` long outdated. Rather than hard-coding the letter `Z` in the time format I preferred to put the offset into the data I format so that it will also give correct output if one day we decide to use another offset (the `OffsetTime` class is seldom used, but seems correct here).

If you get your times as `LocalTime`, that is, without offset, for example from your database, convert like this:

```
    OffsetTime hora = localTimeFromDatabase.atOffset(offset);
```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.